# react-pdf changing page on a pdf cause the page to scroll all up

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I'm using react-pdf ([github link](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf)) to display a pdf on my react app. This is the code:

```
import { useColor } from '@/hooks';
import { ArrowLeftIcon, ArrowRightIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';
import { HStack, Spinner, Text, VStack } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack';

enum Direction {
  Left = '-',
  Right = '+',
}

function PdfComponent({ pdfLink }) {
  const { primary } = useColor();

  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }) {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  }

  const turnPage = (direction: Direction) => {
    if (direction === Direction.Left) {
      if (pageNumber === 1) return;
      setPageNumber(pageNumber - 1);
    }

    if (direction === Direction.Right) {
      if (pageNumber === numPages) return;
      setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <VStack>
      <Document file={pdfLink} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess} loading={<Spinner />}>
        <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
      </Document>
      <HStack>
        <ArrowLeftIcon cursor="pointer" color={primary} onClick={() => turnPage(Direction.Left)} />
        <Text>
          Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
        </Text>
        <ArrowRightIcon cursor="pointer" color={primary} onClick={() => turnPage(Direction.Right)} />
      </HStack>
    </VStack>
  );
}

export default PdfComponent;
```

Everything works fine except for the fact that when I turn the page (if the page has never been seen) the browser scroll the window up, like during a reload, and I have to scroll down to see the entire pdf again.
Once I turn all the pages of the pdf, then this behaviour stops and I can easily change the pages and the window stay focues on the pdf component.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems React will scroll viewport to the top when components change dimensions on the page. Solution is to set `height` on the CSS class - `.react-pdf__Document` of the container Document. `height` attribute should not be in `%`, use other metric like px or vh, this should work -

```
.react-pdf__Page.prevPage {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 1;
}

.react-pdf__Document{
  height: 800px; // change height accordingly
}
```